# Fixed nav and anchor offset issue

Tags: html, css

Given a fixed nav and a few sections with anchors; when clicking on hash links - the fixed nav is overlapping the section anchors.

I've seen a few similar posts but can't seem to find a solution that works for my particular case.

I can't override the `.anchor` styles or use JavaScript to fix that offset or [add any additional HTML elements](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/#article-header-id-0) due to project restrictions.

Although I can add a pseudo-element to `.anchor` - [the hack with a height and a negative margin](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/#article-header-id-1) to balance it out doesn't work in my case because `.anchor` has top padding and border.

```
<h3 class="anchor" id="section-1">Title 1</h3>
<p>Description 1</p>

<h3 class="anchor" id="section-2">Title 2</h3>
<p>Description 2</p>

<h3 class="anchor" id="section-3">Title 3</h3>
<p>Description 3</p>
```

```
.nav {
    position: sticky;
}
.anchor {
    border-top: 1px solid #333940;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
.anchor::before {
}
```

Can anyone please help me figure out if there is a **pure CSS way** to fix the offset of the anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
// e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash,
  $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
   'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-80
  }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
   window.location.hash = target;
  });
});
```

top-80 is the height of space you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I'm aware of this one as well, but as I mentioned - I cannot use JavaScript (or jQuery) due to project requirements and was looking for a pure CSS solution (if it exists).

Comment: Yes, as I also [mentioned in the description](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/#article-header-id-1) - I'm aware of this technique and it only works if no padding or border added to the anchor. But in my case, I have padding and a border which I cannot remove and it doesn't work with that.